# fullPage jquery adding a content block after the slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

I'm using [the fullPage js plugin](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) to develop my website, and I have full page sections throughout the home page. At the bottom of the page, I have a `<footer>` block which isn't a full page section. After installing and using the plugin, I can't seem to scroll to the footer anymore.

My plugin call code:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  'scrollingSpeed': 500,
  'navigation': true,
  'navigationPosition': 'right'
});

$('#right_bot').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
});

$('#right_top').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionUp();
});

$('#backtop').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(1);
});
```

Comment: I don't think that plugin allows for a footer , it is called "FULL PAGE" meaning it take up the  FULL amount of the PAGE, I could be wrong , but I looked at that plugin as well for a project and it seems that each section is meant to use the full page , why dont you put the footer in the section???

Answer (score 0):

Fullpage.js as it names points out is a full-page plugin. It is not suppose to work that way.
You can find similar questions in its repository forum:

- https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/696
- https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/601